# Escape the extra ramification by adding an extra divisor in the double cover

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The following description is from p.3 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.00205.pdf):

Let $Z$ be a smooth projective variety with dimension $2n+1\ge 3$ and positive first Betti number. Fix an embedding $Z\subset \mathbb C\mathbb P^K$ such that $\mathcal O_Z(1)$ is sufficiently ample
in the sense that it is a high enough power of a given ample bundle. Let $P\subset (\mathbb C\mathbb P^K)^*$ be a general linear subspace of the dual space of dimension $d\ge 2$. Then we can
form the incidence variety $Y = \{(z, H)\in Z\times P | z\in H\}$ and there is a projection  $\pi:Y\to P$. Denote the fibre of $\pi$ over $t$ by $X_t$. Let $D_1 = \{t\in P | X_t$ is singular$\}$ be the (reduced) discriminant.

The next step is to form a double cover branched over $D_1$. If $g(x_1,..., x_d) = 0$ is
an affine equation of $D_1$, then the cover $y^2 = g$ may acquire additional ramification
at infinity. It is better to control this in advance by defining

$$D=
\begin{cases}
D_1& \text{if deg}D_1 \text{is even}\\
D_1+D_2& \text{otherwiese}
\end{cases}$$
where $D_2$ is a hyperplane in general position. Now we can find $p': X'\to P$ the double cover branched along $D$.

My question is (1) why "If $g(x_1,..., x_d) = 0$ is
an affine equation of $D_1$, then the cover $y^2 = g$ may acquire additional ramification
at infinity."?

(2) Why the $D$ may escape the additional ramification at infinity by adding an extra divisor $D_2$?

Comment: Because the branch divisor of a double covering of a smooth variety is always divisible by 2 in the Picard group.

Comment: @Sasha I guess you mean $D$ makes sure the divisor is divisible by $2$ in the Picard group but does that guarantee it to be a branch divisor of a double covering of a smooth variety, i.e. is the converse part of your statement true?

Comment: Yes, if $D \sim 2H$ you can define the double covering as the relative spectrum of the sheaf of algebras $\mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O}(-R)$ with the multiplication given by $$\mathcal{O}(-R) \otimes \mathcal{O}(-R) \cong \mathcal{O}(-2R) \cong \mathcal{O}(-D) \to \mathcal{O},$$ where the last arrow is given by the divisor $D$.

Comment: @Sasha  if the cover is a finite cover of degree $n$, then do we have the same statement by replacing $2$ by $n$?